# Displaying the name of the company and the county name

Tags: html, css

I want to put the name of my city and then the name of the company right underneath it and I also want to display the logo on the left. Right now, the city and the logo looks like this:

[image]

I want the "My Company name" directly underneath the City of testing, but right now "My company name is coming on the next line. How can I fix it. Below is my code:

```
     <nav class="navbar" style="background-color: #264653;position:absolute;top:0px;left:50%;transform:translateX(-50%);width:90%">
  <div class="container-fluid">
 
      <span class="navbar-brand">
      <img src="~/Images/infoYellow.png" alt="RCA" width="70" height="70" class="d-inline-block align-middle mr-2" runat="server">
          <span style="font-size:25px;color:white">City of Testing<br />My Company name</span> 
    
   </span>
  </div>
</nav>
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a `display:flex;` on the `span` with `navbar-brand`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar" style="background-color: #264653; position:absolute; top:0px; left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%); width:90%; ">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <span class="navbar-brand" style="display:flex;">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="RCA" width="70" height="70" class="d-inline-block align-middle mr-2" runat="server" />
       <span style="font-size:25px;color:white;">City of Testing<br />My Company name</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</nav>
```

You can find more [info on flexbox here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)